# Android: Google Drive API - Resultcallback never called

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-play-services, google-drive-android-api

I'm using the Google Drive API for a small programm and had no problem with the authentication or execution of tasks. My main problem is that I set a resultcallback for the asynchronious API calls, but the callbacks are never called.
Following Example:

```
    MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
            .setTitle(title).build();
    Timber.d("Creating folder");
    Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(apiClient).createFolder(
            apiClient, changeSet).setResultCallback(
            (DriveFolder.DriveFolderResult driveFolderResult) -> {
                Timber.d("got response");
                if (driveFolderResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    Timber.d("Folder successfully created " + title);
                } else {
                    Timber.d("Could not create Folder " + title);
                }
            });
```

With the apiClient:

```
        return new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .addApi(Drive.API)
            .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(connectionResult ->
                    handleConnectionFailure(connectionResult, mainActivity))
            .build();
```

Im adding the connecting callbacks in another layer, but I think it is not important here because it works.

I see that the Folder is created every time I execute the method. I see that "Creating folder" is printed, but afterwards the resultcallback is not called. The folder is created really fast, therefore I have no clue why onResult is not called.
Does anyone have an idea? The documentation is often outdated and missing complete working examples.

Thank you,

Matthias

Edit:
The code that leads to the execution of the create folder method:

```
    public Observable<Boolean> createFolder(String title) {
    Observable<Boolean> successObservable = Observable.create(subscriber -> {
        createFolderCallback = new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
                apiExecutor.createFolder(subscriber, title);
                apiClient.unregisterConnectionCallbacks(createFolderCallback);
                apiClient.disconnect();
            }

            @Override
            public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                apiClient.unregisterConnectionCallbacks(createFolderCallback);
                apiClient.disconnect();
            }
        };
        apiClient.registerConnectionCallbacks(createFolderCallback);
        apiClient.connect();
    });
    successObservable.compose(ObservableUtils.androidWorkTransformer());
    return successObservable;
}
```

Im not using a different object because I use a singleton object provided in my dagger2-module

Comment: You can look at the sample demo about create a folder in [this Github](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/master/src/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/CreateFolderActivity.java). It prints the message inside the override `public void onResult(DriveFolderResult result)`. You can refer to the new doc about [creating a folder in the root folder](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/folders#create_a_folder_in_the_root_folder).

Comment: Can you show us how you "add connection callback in another layer"? Creating a new instance?

Comment: I already tried all the demos I found and they dont seem to have problems with the callbacks, but I dont see a difference in the code. I followed the new documentation therefore the code is identical. I also use the onResult method, its just hidden due to lambdas.
@seanpj I added the connection callback layer. I inject singleton objects provided by a dagger2 module, therefore all layers use the same instace

Answer (score 4):

The comments encouraged me to read the connection callback layer again and I found out that the disconnect is called before the callback! The `disconnect()` have to be removed from the `onConnected()` Method and has to be executed after the `resultCallback`.
Thank you